# NSColorWell not sending action on click?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nscolor

Inside my .xib, I've placed an `NSColorWell` inside an `NSView`, and connected an `IBAction` in the controller to the `NSColorWell`'s Sent Actions (via File's Owner).  I figured I would respond to a click in my controller and send activate to bring up the `NSColorPanel`.

But unlike other my controls, I'm not getting the `IBAction` called.  Clicking invokes a drag action on the color.  I noticed this control doesn't derive from `NSActionCell` (like all my other controls).  What's the proper control that is supposed to be used to both display a color and invoke the `NSColorWell` when clicked?

(note: this is Xcode/IB 3.2.x)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You listed both `osx` and `ios` in the tags, but I'm guessing this is an OS X problem.

There is a "Bordered" checkbox in IB's Attributes Inspector for NSColorWell. This toggles between a button-style color well, which is what you're asking for, and a color well which you can only drag a color swatch from. Make sure that's checked and you'll get the action like you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, you were absolutely correct!  How in the world would anyone using IB even know that was the function of the "Bordered" checkbox?  Oddly, those borders are really THICK, and this control doesn't support "small" or "mini" control sizes.  Now I just have to figure out how to have my controlled called back -- the NSColorWell "action" doesn't get called.  I assume I need to get the NSColorPanelColorDidChangeNotification?

Comment: You probably don't want to use that because it could come from a different instance of the NSColorPanel. (For example, right-click in any NSTextView and you'll be able to Font>Show Colors. The palette will come up then as well.) Instead, you should bind the object that needs to know about the change to the value of the NSColorWell and then react in -observeValueForKeyPath:…. You could also subclass the well and provide it a delegate which gets called when -setObjectValue: is called, but that sounds like overkill for this case.

Comment: You could of course listen for the ```NSColorPanelColorDidChangeNotification``` and check the notification's ```object``` property to compare to your instance. That's could be even easier than my other two suggestions. :-)