# NSColorWell is not showing colour panel when unchecked Bordered option inside attribute inspector?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolorpanel

Why `NSColorWell` is not showing colour panel when unchecked Bordered option. I have tried with checked bordered, its working fine showing color panel as well. But when unchecked Bordered, not displaying any colour panel. Also i have connected IBaction method to colourwell also. But it is also not responding. Is there any way to make `NSColorWell` work without checking Bordered option??

or else, Is this the bug??

Comment: @DownVoter, Please be care before giving downvote??

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSColorWell not sending action on click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526577/nscolorwell-not-sending-action-on-click)

Comment: @Volker, That one is completely different, My requirement is how to make work NSColorWell when unchecked the bordered option??

Comment: and the link tells you it doesn't work that way... and will only receive drags from color swatches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are asking is not supported.

You can achieve it by doing some tweak. Here is how you can do.

Create a transparent gradient button similar sized to the colorwell and arrange them as shown in this pic.

[image]

Then write an action for the button itself. User will feel that he is clicking on the colorwell.

```
- (IBAction)showColor:(id)sender {

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderFrontColorPanel:nil];

}
```

Comment: Thanks anoop, But the requirement is to use colorwell only. Anyways accepting your answer.

Comment: yeah. ColorWell is still there. What I have done is shown the colour well with an action on a button.